# React Native make child fill all available space

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am new to React Native and I'm trying to make a child component fill all the available space of its container.

The problem is that I *don't* specify the children; I'm designing a reusable component for my app.

How can I make a child (that is passed externally) fill all space within my container? It currently just uses its intrinsic size.

Comment: did you try 'flex:1' as a style for your child component?

Comment: @NaeimFard If I put `flex: 1` or `width: '100%'` in the child component, it works already. My problem is that I'm designing a reusable component, and I want this to be default behavior for my component, *without putting flex: 1 on each child that I supply externally*.

Comment: why do not put a stylesheet in your reusable child component? `const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
   width:'100%'
  }`   then use this style in the View of your child component. <View `style=styles.main>` ...

Comment: @NaeimFard I don't have a reusable child component, it can be any custom or built-in component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it.

I've put `justifyContent: 'space-between'` to the **container** and it made the child(ren) fill available space.